# Object from Observable then Array from Observable inside a foreach. how to order it?Asynchronous Angular 4/5

Tags: json, angular, asynchronous, foreach

Here is my problem.
I'm running a method that sends me a json (method = myTableService.getAllTables ()), to create an object (object = this.myTables).
Then I execute the method for each, for each element of this.myTables I execute a new request (request = this.myTableService.getTableStatut (element.theId)).
I retrieve data from a new json to create an object (object = myTableModel).
Each result will be added to this.myTableListProvisory.
The problem is the order of execution.
It execute the console.log before the end of the for each...
This.myTableListProvisory.length and this.myTableList.length return 0.
How to wait for the end of the for each run before running the console.log?
Thank you

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.myTableService.getAllTables()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.myTables = data;
        this.myTableList = this.getAllTableStatut(this.myTables);
        console.log("this.myTableList.length : " + this.myTableList.length);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      })

}

getAllTableStatut(myTables: any) {

    this.myTableListProvisoire = [];

    myTables.forEach(element => {

      this.myTableService.getTableStatut(element.theId)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.statut = data;
          this.myTableModel = new MyTableModel(element.tableNumber, this.statut.name, element.theId);
          this.myTableListProvisoire.push(this.myTableModel);
        })

      console.log("this.myTableListProvisoire.length : " + this.myTableListProvisoire.length);

    })
    return this.myTableListProvisoire;
}
```

**Result of console.log**

```
this.myTableListProvisoire.length : 0
this.myTableList.length : 0
```

> UPDATE

I have simplified the code ... I put it in its entirety for the understanding. What I need is to sort the array after it is done. The problem is that I don't know how to use a flatMap method in a query inside a foreach ... I have temporarily placed the sort method inside the subscribe which is a bad solution for the performance. That's why I want to do my sort after the creation of the array. Thank you

```
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit {

  myTables: any;
  statut: any;
  myTableModel: MyTableModel;
  myTableList: Array<MyTableModel>;
  myTableListProvisoire: Array<MyTableModel>;
  i: number;
  j: number;
  myTableModelProvisoire: MyTableModel = null;

  constructor(public myTableService: MyTableService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myTableService.getAllTables()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.myTables = data;
        this.myTableList = this.getAllTableStatut(this.myTables);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      })

  }


  getAllTableStatut(myTables: any) {
    this.myTableListProvisoire = [];


    myTables.forEach(element => {
      this.myTableService.getTableStatut(element.theId)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.statut = data;
          this.myTableModel = new MyTableModel(element.tableNumber, this.statut.name, element.theId);
          this.myTableListProvisoire.push(this.myTableModel);

          for (this.j = 0; this.j < this.myTableListProvisoire.length; this.j++) {

            for (this.i = 0; this.i < this.myTableListProvisoire.length - 1; this.i++) {

              if (this.myTableListProvisoire[this.i].getTableNumber() > this.myTableListProvisoire[(this.i + 1)].getTableNumber()) {

                this.myTableModelProvisoire = this.myTableListProvisoire[this.i];
                this.myTableListProvisoire[this.i] = this.myTableListProvisoire[(this.i + 1)];
                this.myTableListProvisoire[(this.i + 1)] = this.myTableModelProvisoire;
              }

            }
          }
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
        })

    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    })

    return this.myTableListProvisoire;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Observables are asynchronous actions and will be executed after finishing the current execution block. So when the js engine comes to your

```
this.myTableService.getTableStatut(element.theId)
 .subscribe(data => {
  this.statut = data;
  this.myTableModel = new MyTableModel(element.tableNumber, this.statut.name, element.theId);
  this.myTableListProvisoire.push(this.myTableModel);
})
```

it will only create a subscription, but the code inside of it will be executed after all the other code in the block. So that's why your `console.log` is being executed before you get any data. So you need to place it inside the `.subscribe` block to see the. I think there can be a better solution to get the data, but I don't know the structure of the app, so I can't advice. If you create an example on https://stackblitz.com/ I could probably help you out with a better solution.

Comment: I have posted a new answer for the understanding of my app. Thanks

Comment: You should post inside your question as a ***UPDATE***